# Как сделать так чтобы когда код выводит в консоль цифры то там цифры были без запятых и кавычек?

Tags: python

```
import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys():
    print((0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))

keyboard.wait('e')
print_pressed_keys()
```

я хочу что бы он выводил не так:

> (0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

а вот так:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: ну так уберите 2 лишние скобки внутри `print`, чтобы выводить не кортеж, а именно числа, разделенные пробелом. `print((0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))` -> `print(0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

Comment: Спасибо что описали всё понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно убрать двойные скобки. Тогда числа выведутся как надо, а не как кортеж.

```
import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys():
    print(0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

keyboard.wait('e')
print_pressed_keys()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Если ответ вам помог, то можете пометить его как решение.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае просто уберите скобки, но если вам нужно реализовать вывод какой то переменной, то используйте распаковку

```
print(*arr)
```

Comment: Попробую этот тоже способ, спасибо вам за помощь